# multiple fetch requests in redux action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following code in a react reducer:

```
 export function getUsers(term) {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    if(term.length > 0) {
      dispatch(requestPeople())
      fetch('http://api.com/api/users/search?q=' + term)
      .then(e => e.json())
      .then(function(response){
        var arr = response
        arr.map(function(i) {
          fetch('http://api.com/api/user/' + i.id + '/photo')
            .then(function(resp){
              i.avatar=resp.url
            }).catch((error) => {
                alert(error)
          });
        })
        dispatch(receivePeople(arr))
      }).catch((error) => {
          alert(error)
      });
    } 
  }
}
```

I need the data from one api fetch call in another api fetch call. I know the way I am doing it above is wrong as this mutates the state and is anti-pattern.

What is the best way to pass the data from one fetch call to another?

Comment: actually you're not mutating state. you're just normalizing some data before it gets set to the state in the `dispatch`, so i don't see a problem here

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the new `async/await` features, you might be able to do something like this:

```
export function getUsers(term) {
    return async function(dispatch, getState) {
        if (term.length > 0) {
            dispatch(requestPeople())
            try {
                const e = await fetch('http://api.com/api/users/search?q=' + term)
                const res = await e.json()
                const arr = res.map(function(i) {
                    try {
                        const photoRes = await fetch('http://api.com/api/user/' + i.id + '/photo');
                        i.avatar = photoRes.url
                    } catch(error) {
                        alert(error)
                    }
                    return i
                }
                dispatch(receivePeople(arr))
            } catch(error) {
                alert(error)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to await `e.json()`? I thought `.json()` it returns a promise.

Comment: I guess you're right. I don't use `fetch`, but it makes sense given the original code. This is untested, but my only concern is maybe the initial `async function...` and how redux handles that. I guess you need `redux-thunk` middleware